# Polymorphic identity + history_mapper

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

I used `history_meta` extension (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/versioned_history/history_meta.html) for SQLAlchemy.

The problem is it does not seem to work well with polymorphic identity, at least when using multiple tables like so:

```
class BaseVersion(Versioned, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'base_version'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'base_version',
        'polymorphic_on':type,
    }
```

(note that `BaseVersion` uses `Versioned` mixin defined in `history_meta`)

Then there's class that inherits from `BaseVersion`:

```
class UnspecifiedVersion(BaseVersion):
    __tablename__ = 'unspecified_version'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('base_version.id'), primary_key=True)
    related_base_version_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('base_version.id'), index=True)
    related_base_version = relationship('BaseVersion', uselist=False, foreign_keys=[related_base_version_id])
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'unspecified_version',
        'inherit_condition':(related_base_version_id==BaseVersion.id)
    }
```

Backend DB is Postgres.

Trying to produce history table for it ends up with error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "base_version_history"      
 [SQL: '
CREATE TABLE unspecified_version_history (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        related_base_version_id INTEGER,
        version INTEGER NOT NULL,
        changed TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
        changed_by VARCHAR,
        PRIMARY KEY (id, version),
        FOREIGN KEY(id, related_base_version_id, version) REFERENCES base_version_history (id, id, version)
)

']
```

Now that's weird because `base_version_history` table definitely has `id` and `version` columns.

Answer (score 0):

I just got through this same error with something similar.  Your issue appears to be with composite primary keys and composite foreign keys that are being generated, as seen in these last two lines of the SQL:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id, version),
FOREIGN KEY(id, related_base_version_id, version) REFERENCES base_version_history (id, id, version)
```

Composite foreign keys need to find matching composite unique keys (basically).  If this table created a two-column primary key, chances are the other one did too, and the foreign key is looking for a three-column unique key.  Also, the same column twice just looks wrong: `(id, id, version)`.  I don't know the extension you are working with so I can't tell you how to fix it.